# Can't build docker package (docker-git) with makepkg

Tags: docker, makefile, archlinux, building

I'm trying to build the **docker-git** package on my archlinux (i686).

I download the package from https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/snapshot/docker-git.tar.gz, untar it and run `makepkg`.

But I get the following output :

```
$ makepkg
==> Making package: docker-git 1:1.9.0.dev.18703.670c488-1 (Tue Oct  6 22:27:42 CEST 2015)
==> Checking runtime dependencies...
==> Checking buildtime dependencies...
==> Retrieving sources...
  -> Updating docker git repo...
Fetching origin
remote: Counting objects: 7, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
remote: Total 7 (delta 5), reused 4 (delta 3), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (7/7), done.
From https://github.com/docker/docker
 + 382d383...29cbec5 refs/pull/16758/merge -> refs/pull/16758/merge  (forced update)
  -> Found docker.service
  -> Found docker.install
  -> Found docker.conf
==> Validating source files with md5sums...
    docker ... Skipped
    docker.service ... Passed
    docker.install ... Passed
    docker.conf ... Passed
==> Extracting sources...
  -> Creating working copy of docker git repo...
Switched to a new branch 'makepkg'
==> Starting pkgver()...
==> Starting prepare()...
==> Removing existing $pkgdir/ directory...
==> Starting build()...
# WARNING! I don't seem to be running in the Docker container.
# The result of this command might be an incorrect build, and will not be
#   officially supported.
#
# Try this instead: make all
#

bundles/1.9.0-dev already exists. Removing.

---> Making bundle: dynbinary (in bundles/1.9.0-dev/dynbinary)
Created binary: bundles/1.9.0-dev/dynbinary/dockerinit-1.9.0-dev
Building: bundles/1.9.0-dev/dynbinary/docker-1.9.0-dev
# _/home/vmonteco/Downloads/docker-git/src/docker/docker
/usr/lib/go/pkg/tool/linux_386/link: running gcc failed: exit status 1
/tmp/go-link-183610645/000007.o: In function `__udivdi3':
(.text+0x8ebc0): multiple definition of `__udivdi3'
/tmp/go-link-183610645/000003.o:(.text+0x740): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

==> ERROR: A failure occurred in build().
    Aborting...
```

Did I forget something? I don't know what the error means.

I also tried `make all` as suggested from the **src/docker** subdirectory but I got :

```
$ make all
docker build -t "docker-dev:makepkg" .
/bin/sh: docker: command not found
Makefile:74: recipe for target 'build' failed
make: *** [build] Error 127
```

NB: I also had to replace the **docker.service** md5 sum in the **PKGBUILD** file, it was invalid before.

Answer (score 0):

Try building with this PKGBUILD: https://gist.github.com/grimsock/8edc7c4f38800f3f992f

Do you have all dependecies installed? Especially from makedepends array?

Comment: Unfortunatelly I get the same error with this one. :/ What did you try?
I'm posting an issue on the maintainer's github.

Comment: I installed it without problem after updating md5sums. I'm using 64bit arch linux, maybe architecture is the problem.

Comment: I just found out that there is a pull request that fixesthe md5 problem on the github. Are you intalling docker-git from AUR or just docker? That is the problem : docker-git is usually meant for i686 architectures. Docker won't work with this architecture and docker-git is the alternative I should be able to use. That is weird.

Comment: I installed package docker-git from AUR.

Comment: I checked it all on i686 architecture and I got the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91740/discussion-between-grimsock-and-vmonteco).